# Best efficient way of converting JSON string to model object

Tags: c#, json, object, model

I have various HttpClient calls which return back a json string. I am currently using the following code to convert the string to a custom 'object' model I have:

```
 public static async Task<List<Models.GSAModels.Meeting>> GetMeetingsAndRacesOnDate(DateTime date)
    {
        string res = "";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("url" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "?gsaappkey=9999"))
            {
                res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }

        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(res);
        List<Models.GSAModels.Meeting> list = jobject["value"].ToObject<List<Models.GSAModels.Meeting>>();

        return list;
    }
```

Is this the most effecient way of doing so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Newtownsoft.Json nuget package

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

Comment: Using             List<Models.GSAModels.Race> datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.GSAModels.Race>>(res); throws an exception error:  : 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[tf.PriceService.Core.Models.GSAModels.Race]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an..